# Can't connect to localhost MySQL database through command line?

Tags: mysql, database, terminal, localhost, sequelpro

Weird issue. Can't connect to localhost MySQL database from command line, but I can through MySQL program, Sequel Pro. Any ideas why? I entered the same user/password, but I'm getting a access denied error for root@localhost

Extra question: can you run MySQL commands within Sequel Pro? I'm pretty new to MySQL, but I'm just trying to change a simple column definition.

EDIT: reset password from within Sequel Pro query for root, and was able to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has different accesses. You can allow a MySQL database to only serve requests from a specific machine, or only from the local machine.

However, note that MySQL differentiates login from "localhost" and from "127.0.0.1".

Try allowing both localhost, 127.0.0.1 and "%" to the account.

Comment: EDIT: Thought this was correct, but it's actually still not working. Still getting access denied.